# Java servlett-Mapping

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, servlets

Hello I have an Embedded Tomcat java application. The tomcat starts and the index.jsp is displayed.

Now i have an An ajax Request which looks like this:

```
function auth(){
username = document.getElementById('login_username').value;
password = document.getElementById('login_pw').value;

if(username.length > 0 && password.length > 0){
   $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/login',
        data: 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        response = response.split(',');
        if(response.length == 2){
            window.location = response[1];
        }
    });
}
```

}

The auth() works. But every time i get a 404 error.

The servlet which should get the Request looks like this:

```
@WebServlet(
        name="login",
        urlPatterns = {"/login","sites/login","login"}
)
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ServletContext context;

    public LoginServlet(){
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Log.log("get");
        resp.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter(); 
        Page p = new Page();
        p.getBody().setContent("GET");
        out.print(p.create());
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Log.log("Post");
        resp.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter(); 
        Page p = new Page();
        p.getBody().setContent("POST");
        out.print(p.create());
    }

    public void init(ServletConfig config)throws ServletException{
        this.context = config.getServletContext();
        Log.log("Login servlet Initialized");
    }
}
```

My question is, why is this not working. Have i to add The servlett to the Tomcat with the tomcat.addServlet(string,string,string) method?;

It works if i create a login.jsp in the base folder of my webapp and if i change the url of the ajax request to login.jsp.

Thanks

Comment: Check the URL being requested in browser console by ajax.Try hitting the same url in browser for possible error logs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your parameter `url: '/login'` in the `$.ajax()` call which makes the request in `http://localhost:8080/login` because of the `/` (slash symbol) in the beginning.

You are most likely expecting it to be something like `http://localhost:8080/MyServletApp/login`. To achieve this remove the `/` from the `url`.

The ajax function call would look like this :

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'login',
    data: 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password
}).done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    response = response.split(',');
    if(response.length == 2){
        window.location = response[1];
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this solution did not work. I tried it before, and now again. I altered the Mapping urls too, but i still get the 404 error. And i dont get a Log entry.

Answer (score 0):

Problem sovled
First i found out that the Annotation work with an Web.xml version above 3.0. So i tried to set the version of my Web.xml to 3.1. Tomcat refused to accept, so i did the servlet mapping in the web.xml